# Cannot run several Pie-Charts in Core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I've been trying to display several CPTPieChart objects from core plot. The first three or 4 run with no problem, but adding more causes a severe crash.

The crash is within the method

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext.
```

It tries to call [super drawInContext:theContext]; and crashes there. It crashes in the same place on the device and simulator.

I think it's because it has released something too early, but I cannot seem to find what.

Any suggestions?

Here is the crash log:

```
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3006bc98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   FinGame                         0x00abc1ce -[CPTPieChart renderAsVectorInContext:] (CPTPieChart.m:399)
2   FinGame                         0x00a9d08c -[CPTLayer drawInContext:] (CPTLayer.m:266)
3   FinGame                         0x00a7fb04 -[CPTPlot drawInContext:] (CPTPlot.m:326)
4   QuartzCore                      0x352a6d24 backing_callback(CGContext*, void*) + 32
5   QuartzCore                      0x352a6776 CABackingStoreUpdate + 1226
6   QuartzCore                      0x352a6178 -[CALayer _display] + 724
7   QuartzCore                      0x352a5e86 -[CALayer display] + 134
8   QuartzCore                      0x3529a706 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 178
9   QuartzCore                      0x3529a1c6 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 214
10  QuartzCore                      0x35299fd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
11  QuartzCore                      0x352ec1ee CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 34
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32919b7c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 156
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x328edf78 _pthread_exit + 112
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x328ef462 pthread_exit + 22
15  Foundation                      0x3431f06e +[NSThread exit] + 10
16  Foundation                      0x3439d5de __NSThread__main__ + 990
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x328ee30a _pthread_start + 242
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x328efbb4 thread_start + 0
```

Comment: Do you have multiple pie charts in one graph or multiple hosting views, each with one graph and one pie chart?

Comment: @EricSkroch: There are multiple hosting views: each graph (a CPTPieChart) added to a CPTXYGraph which is then added to its own CPTGraphHostingView.

Comment: Where is it crashing? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @EricSkroch: I've added the stack trace for the crashed thread

Comment: @EricSkroch:I've solved my problem, it was an overzelous garbage collector. You can rest easy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a case of a missing "retain". As soon as I added this (and the requisite release) it was golden.